# 一つのファイルの中で、実行コードとテストを同時に記入するさいのプラクティス

Tags: ruby

勉強のため、簡単なコードを書くさいに、ファイルを分割せずに、一つのファイルにてテストを書いたほうが簡潔で良いことがあります。

他のプログラミング言語だと、Pythonなら[DocTest](http://docs.python.jp/3.5/library/doctest.html)であったり、あるいはRacketだと[rackunit](http://docs.racket-lang.org/rackunit/)のように、一つのファイルにてテストを記入する方法があります。

Rubyだと、[minitest/unit](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.1.0/library/minitest=2funit.html)が存在しており、確かにこれで、一つのファイルにて`require 'minitest/autorun'`をすると、コマンド上ではテストが走ります。

ですが、`irb`でファイルを`require`したあとに、REPLを終了させると、テストが走ってしまうので、違和感があります。

確かに、上記の方法では、最低限の「一つのファイルで実行コードとテストを同時に記入する」という要件は満たせるのですが、もしかしたら、これはバッドノウハウなのでは、という疑問がぬぐえません。

もし、Rubyで「一つのファイルの中で、実行コードとテストを同時に記入する」ときには、どういう方法を取るのが良いのでしょうか？

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$0`/`$PROGRAM_NAME`と擬似変数の`__FILE__`を比較して、直接ファイルが実行された場合のみ`require 'minitest/autorun'`するとよいのではないでしょうか。

http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.1.0/method/Kernel/v/0.html
http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.1.0/doc/spec=2fvariables.html#pseudo

### 例

```
class C
  def foo
    'foo'
  end
end

require 'minitest/unit'

class TestC < Minitest::Unit::TestCase
  def setup
    @c = C.new
  end

  def test_foo
    assert_equal 'foo', @c.foo
  end
end

if $0 == __FILE__
  require 'minitest/autorun'
end
```

Comment: 実例みかけたのでコメントしておきます。nibbler gemではテストも`if $0 == __FILE__`の中に書いているみたいです(テスト以外では使わないコードですからね)。 https://github.com/mislav/nibbler/blob/master/lib/nibbler.rb